# Codeigniter, Fat models and skinny controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I’m busy with my first codeigniter “practice” project. I’ve used flexi_auth as a validation library and really liked the way that they implement the form validation in the model and not in the controller, thus sticking to MVC(Fat models) principal.

I’m trying to build another one of my forms with the same logic but for the life of me I can’t seem to get the error message set by validation errors from the model via the controller to the view. Please note I’m using a layout helper, thus the abnormal call to view.

Any help will be appreciated. Here is my code:

Controller:

```
//Start Information Desk Query()
public function information()
{
  if ($this->input->post(‘informationForm_submit’))
  {
  $this->load->model(‘contact_model’);
  $this->contact_model->information_post();
  // information_post validation failed
  }

  $this->data[‘title’] = ‘Information Desk’;
  $this->layout->show(‘contact/information_view’, $this->data);

}
//End Information Desk Query()
```

Model:

```
//Start Information Request()
public function information_post()
{

  $validation_rules = array(
  array(‘field’ => ‘informationEmail’, ‘label’ => ‘Email’, ‘rules’ => ‘required|valid_email’),
  array(‘field’ => ‘informationQuery’, ‘label’ => ‘Message’, ‘rules’ => ‘required|max_length[500]’)
  );

  $this->form_validation->set_rules($validation_rules);

  if ($this->form_validation->run())
  {
  return TRUE;
  }
  else
  {
  $this->data[‘message’] = validation_errors(’<li class=“error_msg”>’, ‘</li>’);
  return FALSE;
  }

}
//End Information Request()
```

View:

```
<?php

      if (! empty($message))
      {
        echo ‘<div class = “error_message”>
        <div class =“error_header”>Please correct the following</div>
        <div class = “error_image my-icons-Actions-window-close-icon”></div>
        <ul class = “error_text”>’.$message.’</ul></div>’;
      }
  ?>
```

****Please note that the form validation is functional in this code. If I put the following:
echo $this->data[‘message’];

....in the model then the errors are displayed but obviously not as a part of my view file but before it. 
PS. please take it easy if this is a stupid question but I am a newbie to codeigniter and actually to MVC.

Comment: I would not that, if you code has "models" (as in plural), you already have destroyed the model. MVC is made up from two major layers: model layer and presentation layer. Model is not a class or object, but a layer, that contains several groups of class/instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting property of model and not getting it in controller

you should do something like this in your controller:

```
if ($this->input->post('informationForm_submit'))
{
    $this->load->model('contact_model');
    $this->contact_model->information_post();
    // required addition
    $this->data['message'] = $this->contact_model->data['message'];
}
```

Comment: Thank you Ochi. This helped. Great stuff.